# MigraDoc Private Font Error - An entry with the specified family name already exists

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using the MigraDoc DLLs (WPF build) for generating a pdf and I have added the code given below that does the work of adding a new private font:

```
                XPrivateFontCollection pfc = XPrivateFontCollection.Global;
                Uri myuri = new Uri(Server.MapPath("/Assets/Rupee_Foradian.ttf"));
                pfc.Add(myuri, "./#Rupee Foradian");
```

The PDF generates successfully with the font loading properly and displaying as expected, but when I try for the second time to create the PDF I get an **ArgumentException: An entry with the specified family name already exists**

Can anyone please help me out on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name `XPrivateFontCollection.Global` implies the font collection is **global** and exists only once.

Your code should add the font only once (for the first document) and not every time you create a document.

Edit:
To execute code only once you can use another global variable (e.g. a static class member):

```
static bool _privateFontsInstalled;

private static void LoadPrivateFonts()
{
    if (!_privateFontsInstalled)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/");
            PdfSharp.Drawing.XPrivateFontCollection.Add(uri, "...");
            PdfSharp.Drawing.XPrivateFontCollection.Add(uri, "...");
            PdfSharp.Drawing.XPrivateFontCollection.Add(uri, "...");

            _privateFontsInstalled = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how do i go about adding it only once in the code.. ?

Comment: @Neville Updated my post.

Comment: Thank you so much ! appreciate it !